# React: split state and functions from view, but too many props to pass down

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying a new style that separates state definition and functions from components.

e.g.

```js
// Comp.js
const Comp = (props) => {
  const { state1, setState1, func } = props;
  ...
  return <div>...</div>;
}

// CompContainer.js
import Comp from "./Comp"
const CompContainer = (props) => {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState(null);
  
  const func = (arg) => {
  ...
  }
  return <Comp state1={state1} setState1={setState1} func={func} />
}
```

Paradoxically, for small components with very little states and functions work great with this style. The logic is clean, and a single file becomes small and easy to read; but my purpose is to separate logic from view for big components.

However for big components, there're many props and states and functions.

I have to pass a long list of props to the view, and (although optional) define a long list of `propTypes`, and destructing a long list.

Is there any *magic* way to shorten this props list to make life easier?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off using something like [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) to modify a shared object.

Else you could pass all the props of a parent to the child in your return, but definitely not recommended.

```
<Comp {...props} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm using react context and graphql client for state management. The question is not about state management for a project, but about a single component.

Comment: I believe your goal was to separate the logic from the view - which would drive those props, states, functions into react-context which would leave your components to be more "pure components".

Comment: You might also be interested in https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context